# PHP regex to extract controller and action from string

Tags: php, regex, string, symfony, routes

So I am developing a Symfony2 application. If you know what i am talking about you know how are routes structured there so I need to extract the routes and their controllers and actions.

I found how to extract the route object but I can't extract the controller and action, but i have the string which has them.

So I have this string: `Acme\SomeBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction`

All string have similar structure. All strings end with ControllerName::ActionName. Controller name always ends with "Controller" and action name always end with "Action". So I couldnt figure how to extract theese values from the string. I am new to regex I read about it but I don't have any clue how to do this. Please help me, any help apreciated :)

Example string:

```
`Emca\AnotherBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction`
```

Example output:

```
SecurityController
loginAction
```

I think you can't do this only with one regex but two may be enough. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you use symfony's router for this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#usage, or the request object? They will have already done this work for you.

Comment: #vascowhite I need to extract all routes and their actions. So I cannot do it on the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example can be found in symfony's [ControllerNameParser](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerNameParser.php#L84) class:

```
$controller = 'Acme\YourBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction';

if (0 === preg_match('#^(.*?\\\\Controller\\\\(.+)Controller)::(.+)Action$#', $controller, $match)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The "%s" controller is not a valid "class::method" string.', $controller));
}

$className      = $match[1];
$controllerName = $match[2];
$actionName     = $match[3];
```